# Cannot assign css rules for div element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to add some css rules to a div element using an ID SELECTOR
But it does nothing..

This is the result of my code:
[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#header {
  background: #DEDEDE;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

#header .flex-container {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1028px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* put the container on the middle */
}

#header .flex-container #logoPicture {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#tal {
  border: solid;
}

#header .flex-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

#header .flex-container #logo {
  font-family: "Bauhaus 93";
  font-size: 350%;
  color: #E83303;
}

#header .flex-container ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  /* avoud the default padding to the left */
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic", Tahoma;
}

#header .flex-container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #E83303;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="logoPicture">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cvO9xwB.png">
    </div>
    <div id="logo">RAPITEC</div>
    <div id="tal">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Shop</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Select the child class like so `#header > .flex-container`. You forgot to add the child selector.

Comment: ^ Doesn't change things apart from being more specific, the styles should successfully apply in both cases.

Comment: @Tal Rofe Which ID are you talking about?

Comment: @godof23 Yes, but I assumed it's the children because why would he change the width of `flex-container` over and over like that? He can't apply so many witdths like that to a single element.

Comment: i have create a fiddle and the result is pretty different from your image https://jsfiddle.net/n4mbeLtd/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
#tal {
  border: solid;
}
```

Try:

```
#tal {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You could also write this like:

```
#tal {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
```

When putting your code into [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kboedges/pen/428ecc7fabfc2717a10ddd4dc1726a6d), I am seeing a border (Chrome and Firefox on Mac). It appears that our default `border-width` and/or `border-color` values are different. It's best to be specific about those two things.